# Should private beta users be able to edit all questions

Tags: feature-request, private-beta

Currently you have to have a high reputation to edit someone else's question. I think this is great most of the time but during the private beta it seems like the limit should be lowered quite a bit to allow users to edit questions during the private beta. Maybe 150 or something would make sense. The point of the private beta is to get good questions up there and allowing the edits at a lower level would give us the chance to "fix up" some of those initial questions right away.

Comment: IIRC Everything was at reputation of 10 or something crazy like that in private beta. I believe that I was editing people's questions all the time in Programmers private beta

Comment: I'm part of the DBA.SE private beta right now and have 190 rep. and don't have the ablity to edit other peoples questions or answers.

Comment: @TheLQ - I don't think so. The rep requirements for Programmers' were the same as for every other site. You may have been thinking of the public beta.

Comment: Hmm, strange. +1 from me then

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is already the case; see

[Reputation requirements compared](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58587/reputation-requirements-compared)

specifically

```
                            private   public
                            beta      beta     gold   so
Edit other people's posts   500       1000     2000   2000
```

Comment: That's cool but it still seems like 500 is a bit high. DBA.SE is nearing the end of the private beta and only 5 people have enough rep to edit others. Is DBA low in this respect or is that intentional?

Comment: @bitoff that's a sign of a not-particularly-healthy beta, but the real test is in public beta