# What is a "Gold" site?

Tags: discussion, graduating-sites

I thought there were 3 states of an SE site: Private Beta, Public Beta, and Full-blown SE site.  Then I stumbled across [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58587/reputation-requirements-compared) and [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74463/should-private-beta-users-be-able-to-edit-all-questions), both of which indicate a state between(?) Public Beta and Full-blown SE site.  What is this "Gold" state?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Gold just means live, the state of being officially launched after the public beta is done.  It's not a state between public beta and "full-blown".  Jeff was simply comparing live (gold) Stack Exchange sites to *Stack Overflow*, which is a completely different scale from any of the other sites.

Comment: Kind of like a "gold master" in that it's what is "released to production" but not "gold" like "a wonderful thing". +1 for the answer, but I'ld like to call out that part about SO being totally a different beast than the rest of the SE2.0 sites ;)