# Who can 'peer-review' suggested edits in private beta?

Tags: support, suggested-edits, private-beta

I know [you need less reputation in order to do edits during private beta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/74478/157047) (500), but you can always suggest edits. These suggested edits need to be peer reviewed.

What does it take to be able to peer review edits during private beta?

When flagging, [apparently the SO staff are moderators at the start of private beta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/59692/157047). Is this the same with suggested edits? Do they get notified of them?

Comment: +1, I have many suggested edits pending on Cog.Sci private beta!

Comment: MY guess is you can approve them at 500 when you can do your own edits, but the privileges page does not specify this best I can tell.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

At 500 you can approve edits.

At 1000 you will see it in the top bar and be able to manage it easier.

[image: Tools and suggested edits]

[image: A suggested edit in Movies]

But seeing that the suggested edits links are not in Tools but in /review try seeing if this link will work

/review/suggested-edits

Cannot remember if it does and I am not currently in a private beta.

As Steven noted,

> When you have earned at least 750 reputation, you will receive the “approve tag wiki edits” privilege and will be allowed to view this page.

Sounds like there is a need (feature request?) to allow access to that page if one has post edit privileges.

Comment: _"When you have earned at least 750 reputation, you will receive the “approve tag wiki edits” privilege and will be allowed to view this page."_

Comment: @StevenJeuris well there you have it. 500 to approve edits. 750 to see all current pending edits. Of course you *could* just start clicking all the questions to see any pending edits >.<